Moved XLM from Binance to the XLM blockchain a year ago, unsure how to access now
I first sent a smallish amount which resulted in a Create Account and then a larger amount.
Looking at the Binance withdrawal screen, I would have had to enter a destination address so presumably this would have been provided by the exchange/wallet I was sending it to.
I can only think I transferred the XLM as I didn't want to leave it on a centralised exchange, the trouble is I can't work out which wallet it went to.. can't be Metamask and I don't use the wallets that are generally recommended for use with XLM. I've checked my cold wallets too.
So there are the transactions on the chain, but I've absolutely no idea how to access my XLM now, has anyone any suggestions ?
